# Selected row color not changed when another row select in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am Using Material-UI Collapsible table. I intended to change the selected row color and I implemented it using this css:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  tableRow: {
    '&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'purple',
      '& > .MuiTableCell-root': {
        color: 'yellow'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

and changed table row like this:

```
<TableRow
   hover
   key={row.id}
   onClick={() => {
   setSelectedID(row.id);
   }}
   selected={selectedID === row.id}
   className={classes.tableRow}
>
```

In this case I am facing another problem. When I click on another row, it is not de-select previous row.
[image]
Please help to figure out the solution.

find source code on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsible-table-yd44p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the State in the Parentcomponent `<Table />` because when you just set the State in each Row the State won't change for the other Rows.

Solution:

1. Put the State in the `<Table />`
2. Pass the `setSelectedID` as props to the rows (`<CustomRow onSelectRow={setSelectedID} />`)
3. Handle onClick with the `props.onSelectRow(row.id)`
4. pass the Parents State (`selectedID`) as props as well and check for `props.selectedID === row.id`

**Complete Example**

```
const Parent = () => {

   const [selectedID, setSelectedID] = useState(null)

   return (
      // ...
      <Row onSelectRow={setSelectedID} selectedID={selectedID} />
      <Row onSelectRow={setSelectedID} selectedID={selectedID} />
      <Row onSelectRow={setSelectedID} selectedID={selectedID} />
      <Row onSelectRow={setSelectedID} selectedID={selectedID} />
      // ...
   )
}

const Row = (props) => {
   const {setSelectedID, selectedID} = props
   return (
      <TableRow
        onClick={() => {
          setSelectedID(row.id);
        }}
        selected={selectedID === row.id}
      >
      //...
      </TableRow>
   )
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother. I am grateful to you.